# Casting Future<List<String>> to a List<String> throws an exception in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function:

```
  Future<List<String>> _readJson(String path) async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + path;
    String response = await File(appDocPath).readAsString();

    final data = await (json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();

    return data;
  }
```

As you can see, the output is a `Future<List<String>>`. I want to assign the output of this function to a new list like this (to be able to iterate through the elements:

```
  void _function(Map<dynamic, dynamic> playbackData) {
    ...

    List<String> jsonList = readJSON('landmarks.json') as List<String>;

    for(int i = 0; i <= jsonList.length - 1; ++i){
      print(jsonList[i]);
    }
  }
```

But this is my error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

I know that the output is a Future List of Strings but I am deliberately casting it to a List of strings for that purpose. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you have that second `await`. Have you tried to replace your `final data` line with: `final data = (json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();` ?

Comment: Have you tried to label your `_function` as `async` and then `await` for `readJSON` response? Maybe  that'll do.

Comment: Also, this is never going to work `List<String> jsonList = readJSON('landmarks.json') as List<String>;` since you need to await the returned future. You are working with async code. A `Future` means something that is going to potentially have a value later at some point. You can therefore not just cast this directly to a value. The point of `await` is to halt the current running code and let other events on the event queue running so the future might get a value. When the future gets a value, your code is ready to be executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: "Not sure why you have that second await. Have you tried to replace your final data line with: final data = (json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(); "

Tried it. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just await the return and you will get List<String>

and change the return type to

```
_readJson(String path) async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + path;
    String response = await File(appDocPath).readAsString();

    final data = json.decode(response);

    return data;
  }
```

Then to read its data

```
List<dynamic> jsonList = await readJSON('landmarks.json');
for(int i = 0; i <= jsonList.length - 1; ++i){
      print(jsonList[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `A value of type 'Future<List<String>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.`

Comment: List<String> _readJson(String path) async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + path;
    String response = await File(appDocPath).readAsString();

    final data = await (json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();

    return data;
  }

Comment: Could you add that to your answer? Hard to read..

Comment: done please check

Comment: Do I need to change anything in `_function()`?

Comment: Also. How come the function isn't Future?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Comment: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: Was way ahead of you and changed it to List<dynamic>. Just before the for loop, I placed this log `print('jsonList size: '+ jsonList.length.toString());` and the output is `I/flutter (28233): jsonList size: 0`

Comment: can you add a print statement before its returned from the method? and see if it really passes something

Comment: I added `print('data length: '+data.length);` in readJSON and this is the output: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: print('data length: ${data.length}');

Comment: `data length: 0`

Comment: Which means that there is no data that's fetched

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to read a `Future<List<String>>` with the following code. Just `await` for your result before assigning it to `jsonList`. Don't forget to mark your function as `async` too:

```dart
void _function(Map<dynamic, dynamic> playbackData) async {
  ...

  List<String> jsonList = await readJSON('landmarks.json');

  for (int i = 0; i <= jsonList.length - 1; ++i) {
    print(jsonList[i]);
  }
}
```